# html/javascript -- Creating a hint option to Questions

Tags: javascript, html

It is kind of hard to explain since im very new to html and javascript.

What i need it on my question ( multiple choice) I need a hint button. and when that hint button is clicked will display a couple of sentences that may point the person in the right direction. ( and is toggable. so clicking the hint button again will make it disapear.)

Any help would be much appreciated.

```
<form method="POST" name="Quiz">

    <font face="Arial"><big><big>This is a Quiz</big></big></font></p>

<div class="qheader">
    1) What is the colour of Irn-Bru</div>
<div class="qselections">
    <input type="radio" value="a" name="question1">a) Orange.<br>
    <input type="radio" value="b" name="question1">b) Red.<br>
    <input type="radio" value="c" name="question1">c) Green.<br>
    <input type="radio" value="d" name="question1">d) Purple.<br>
</div>
```

Comment: You should post any code you've tried to this point, even if it's only HTML.  This will get you a better and quicker response.

Comment: Good idea. its a lot of pages i have though. il post a clip of how i coded the question.

Answer (score 1):

I threw together a quick demo similar to what ryanyuyu suggested.

[button click demo](http://codepen.io/ryanjgill/pen/MYKZxW)

```
$('button').on('click', function () {
  $('div.hint').toggleClass('hidden');
});
```

You might want to look into using a 'tooltips' that would show/hide when a user hovers over an icon next to the question. [go here](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/) and scroll down to tooltips. It might be a better fit for your situation.

Comment: I tried it your way. I oculd get the button on the page and the text was hidden. the problem i had was it wouldnt show the text once the button was clicked..

what i basically done was copy paste your demo code into my js, css and html files

Comment: This solution would require that you have jQuery. Are there any errors thrown when you click the button?

Answer (score 0):

Using an [onClick event](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onclick.asp) for an HTML button will let you call a javascript method, where you can do whatever you need, including showing/hiding text.  Depending on what framework you are using, there could be better solutions more consistent within the framework.

Answer (score 0):

You'd have to first hidden div containing the hint using HTML/CSS.

HTML:

```
<div class="hidden" id="hint">This is the hint for the question</div>
```

CSS:

```
.hidden {
    display: none;
}
```

Then you'd have to create a button and make an onClick event listener to manage whether the hint would be displayed or not. I'd recommend looking into jQuery's [toggle](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/) function for it. It'd be something like..

HTML:

```
<input type="button" id="show_hint" value="Show Hint">
```

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#show_hint').click(function() {
        $('#hint').toggle();
    });
});
```

Simple Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/d8og32qa/